# Find the parametric equation of the surface cut from a sphere by a cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, parametrization

Find the parametric equation of the surface cut from a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$ by a cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Attempt: I want to use spherical coordinates. Solving the sphere and cone, the surface is given by $$S:z=\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}, ~~ x^2+y^2\leq 8.$$

A parametrization is given by

$$r(u,v)=(4 \,cos \,u\,sin\, v, 4 \,sin \,u\,sin \,v, 4 \,cos \,v)$$
where $u\in[0,2\pi]$.

**Question: If my argument is correct, what is the range of $v$ and how to find it. If possible, please provide me a figure by marking the surface cut.**

Is the range of $v$ is $[0,\pi/4]$, since, $4\cos\, v=z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{16\sin^2\, v\cos^2\, u+16\sin^2\, v\sin^2\, u}=4\sin\, v$ implying $tan\, v=1$.

[image]

Comment: The surface cut is the circle  at $z=\sqrt{8}$

Comment: Anything else we could do for you, sir? Geogebra or Desmos allow you to draw the figures. Your equation with $S:z=...$ is already a parametrization. The maximal polar angle $v$ is the one between the north pole $(0,0,4)$ and $(2,2,\sqrt{8})\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you. Fig added. I am not able to understand the range of $v$ still now. How to get the point $(2,2,\sqrt{8})$. Why it is not $\pi/4$ since, $4\cos\, v=z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{16\sin^2\, v\cos^2\, u+16\sin^2\, v\sin^2\, u}=4\sin\, v$ implying $tan\, v=1$

Comment: $(2,2,\sqrt8)$ is written in Cartesian coordinates; note how it satisfies $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$.

Comment: Your $\pi/4$ is correct. You could have obtained it also by
$$
\cos v=\frac{\langle(0,0,4),(2,2,\sqrt{8})\rangle}{4\sqrt{4+4+8}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\,.
$$